# How to "allow edit" newly added fields in a form? for Dynamics AX (AX7/D365)

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax7, dynamics-365-operations

I've added a new field to my form **EcoResProductDetailsExtended**, but when I click edit it does not allow me to edit it. The properties for allowing edit is already set to Yes. The form contains the method **setAllowEditFields() and setAllowEditField()** but it is ***private*** so it means I can't make an extension of it nor call it.

Is there anyway or method that I can allow the form to edit my newly added fields?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `AllowEdit` property in 3 locations:

1. The table field
   \Data Dictionary\Tables\InventTable\Fields\ABCValue
2. The form datasource field
   \Forms\EcoResProductDetailsExtended\Data Sources\InventTable\Fields\ABCValue
3. The form control
   \Forms\EcoResProductDetailsExtended\Designs\DesignList\CostABC_ABCValue

Also, the datasource should allow edit, the Edit button be activated, permissions allow edit etc.

Comment: Hi Jan. Already checked. Everything has "Yes" in their AllowEdit property. and still I can't edit them.

Answer (score 0):

Although method `setAllowEditFields` is private, it is called from public method `setItemStockedDependentObjects`. You can create a post-event handler for `setItemStockedDependentObjects` and make your field editable there.

```
[PostHandlerFor(formStr(EcoResProductDetailsExtended), formMethodStr(EcoResProductDetailsExtended, setItemStockedDependentObjects))]
public static void Post_setItemStockedDependentObjects(XppPrePostArgs args)
{
    // your code here
}
```